# How does someone implement an OpenID Relying party with Socko webserver?

Tags: akka, reactive-programming, socko

I am using socko webserver which is great for websockets and the like. I would like to let people authenticate against it using OpenID. I cannot see any examples of using a library such as openid4java with Socko. How does one do this?

Comment: Hey if someone is going to downvote do you mind pointing out why you don't think the question is well put or appropriate.

Comment: Figured this out myself and created a demo app at https://github.com/simbo1905/socko-openid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no-one had any hints I wrote my own demo app [socko-openid](https://github.com/simbo1905/socko-openid) on github. It uses the [openid4java](https://code.google.com/p/openid4java/) library as documented on a wicket based demo by [J Steven Perry](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-openid/). A write up of the code including how sessions and cookies are handled is written up as [openid-authentication-with-socko-webserver](http://simbo1905.wordpress.com/2014/05/05/openid-authentication-with-socko-webserver/).